# JSON mocking fails with Internal Salesforce Error when working with ChangeEvent records

Tags: apex, unit-test

Most of the time I write my test classes using JSON mocking and I am trying to follow the same for class that works with AccountChangeEvent but it is failing with error `Internal Salesforce Error.`

I confirm that Change Data Capture is enabled for Account object in Setup and below is a trimmed version of the actual issue I am experiencing.

**Actual class**:

```
public class AccountChangeEventTriggerHandler {
    public static void doSomething(List<AccountChangeEvent> aceList){

        for(AccountChangeEvent eventObj: aceList){
            EventBus.ChangeEventHeader headerObj = eventObj.ChangeEventHeader;
            System.debug(headerObj.changetype);
            System.debug(headerObj.getChangeType());
        }
    }

}
```

**Test class**:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestClass {

    @isTest
    private static void test_something(){
        Test.enableChangeDataCapture();
        String mockAccChangeEventJSON = '{ "schema": "GGWw16s_SHeGY3evDkDi0Q", "payload": { "LastModifiedDate": "2020-01-07T23:58:01.000Z", "Type": "Standard", "ChangeEventHeader": { "commitNumber": 10698374931760, "commitUser": "005f4000003n80HAAQ", "sequenceNumber": 3, "entityName": "Account", "changeType": "UPDATE", "changedFields": [ "LastModifiedDate", "Type" ], "changeOrigin": "", "transactionKey": "000612c5-4356-287b-b340-ab6549c22a21", "commitTimestamp": 1578441481000, "recordIds": [ "001M000001B8JmhIAF" ] } }, "event": { "replayId": 1486121 } }';
        List<AccountChangeEvent> aceList = new List<AccountChangeEvent>();
        aceList.add((AccountChangeEvent)JSON.deserialize(mockAccChangeEventJSON, AccountChangeEvent.class));
        AccountChangeEventTriggerHandler.doSomething(aceList);
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a troubling pattern to hear you using as common practice. It should be more of a last resort.

Comment: The entire point of Test.enableChangeDataCapture() is so you don't need to mock anything. Just insert and update an account.